# Shell script help to fix it please

Tags: shell

Example i run
sh mycode Manu gg44

And I need to get file with name Manu
with content:
gg44
192.168.1.2.(second line) (this number I explain below)

(in the directory DIR=/h/Manu/HOME/hosts there is already file Alex
cat Alex
ff55
198.162.1.1.(second line))

So mycode creates file named Manu with the first line gg44 and generate IP at the second line.
BUT for generating IP he has compare with Alex file IP. So second line of Manu has to be 198.162.1.2. If we have more than one files in the directory then we have to check all second lines of all files and then generate according to them.

```
[CODE]
DIR=/h/Manu/HOME/hosts       #this is a directory where i have my files (structure of the files above)
for j in $1 $2             #$1 is Manu; $2 is gg44
do
              if [ -d $DIR ]             #checking if directory exists (it exists already)
              then                        #if it exists
              for i in $*           #  for every file in this directory do operation
              do
              sort /h/ManuHOME/hosts/* |  tail -2 | head -1            # get second line of every file
                IFS="." read A B C D                   # divide number  in second line into 4 parts (our number 192.168.1.1. for example)
      if [ "$D" != 255 ]             #compare D (which is 1 in our example: if its less than 255)
     then
     D=` expr $D + 1 `             #then increment it by 1
       else
     C=` expr $C + 1 `          #otherwise increment C and make D=0
     D=0
fi
           echo "$2 "\n" $A.$B.$C.$D." >/h/Manu/HOME/hosts/$1
    done done                  #get $2 (which is gg44 in example as a first line and get ABCD as a second line)[/CODE]
```

In the result it creates file with name Manu and first line, but second line is totally wrong. It gives me ...1.
Also error message
sort: open failed: /h/u15/c2/00/c2rsaldi/HOME/hosts/yu: No such file or directory

yu n ...1.

Comment: "yu n ...1"? I can't keep up with these new acronyms.

Comment: First, you miss a `fi` statement. The rest is to messy... Indent your code properly, that will helps.

Comment: test your script with : sh -x -v  mycode Manu gg44

Comment: Egads! You have to start indenting your code.

Answer (score 0):

```
#!/bin/bash
dir=/h/Manu/HOME/hosts
filename=$dir/$1
firstline=$2

# find the max IP address from all current files:
maxIP=$(awk 'FNR==2' $dir/* | cut -d. -f4 | sort -nr | head -1)
ip=198.162.1.$(( maxIP + 1 ))

cat > $filename <<END
$firstline
$ip
END
```

I'll leave it up to you to decide what to do when you get more than 255 files...